# Tenancy for laravel selecting table from tenant database and not from central database

Tags: laravel, multi-tenant

I'm creating multi-tenant project with Laravel (it's very confusing) and currently I have situation where I want to access nova dashboard from tenant domain and it's selecting all tables from tenant database instead of selecting tenant databases from tenant db and other tables from central database?

Is there any fix for this?

Comment: Can you tell the github address of the package you're using? All tenancy packages have similar names. Your package name that you're using should be in your composer.json

Comment: https://github.com/archtechx/tenancy